# Post-commit hook to send error message to the client

Tags: windows, svn, svn-hooks

Am using svnserver in my windows(7) machine.

I need to send errror message from post-commit.bat to the svn client(may be any client) in windows.

any idea to do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this accidentally where the post commit hook failed and the failure message is reported to the user.

GUI clients *should* display the error message.

We encountered this when we had scmbug installed and its connection to bugzilla was broken. This would suggest that you just need to get the post-commit hook to return an error code (return non-zero) and output the error message you want displayed.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Note that the error should be written to stderr, not stdout for it to be displayed by clients.

So for an 'echo' to be visible through clients you should use

```
echo Non-Fatal error: Commit succeeded but issue tracker not updated >&2
```